# confusion about the definition Hausdorff measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

3 down vote favorite

I am studying real analysis and I have some problems in understanding properties of Hausdorff measure.

Let $\mathcal{E}_\delta$ be collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^N$ whose diameter is less then $\delta$. Now $\mathcal{E}_\delta$ has the property that for every $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ there exists a countable collection $\{ Q_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{E}_\delta$ such that $E \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}Q_n$ (to see this we may observe that $\mathbb{R}^N$ could be partitioned in a numerable union of dyadic cubes, each with diameter arbitrarily small).

Now define $\mathcal{H}_{\alpha,\delta}(E)=\inf \left\{ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{diam}(E_n)^\alpha \,\middle|\, E \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \ \text{and} \ \left\{E_n \right\} \subseteq \mathcal{E}_\delta \right\}$
By the properties of infimum we deduce that if $\delta_1 \le \delta_2$ then $\mathcal{H}_{\alpha,\delta_2}(E) \le \mathcal{H}_{\alpha,\delta_1}(E)$. So it make sense define the Hausdorff outer $\alpha$-measure of E by $\mathcal{H}_\alpha(E)=\sup_{\delta>0} \mathcal{H}_{\alpha,\delta}=\lim_{\delta \to 0^+}\mathcal{H}_{\alpha,\delta}$
Now $\mathcal{H}_\alpha$ is an outer measure, and if consider the collection $\mathcal{A} of sets E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ such that $\mathcal{H}_\alpha(A)=\mathcal{H}_\alpha(E \cap A) + \mathcal{H}_\alpha(A\setminus E), \ \ \forall A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N \ \ \ \ \ (*)$
we can prove (using the Carathéodory Extension Theorem) that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and we say that $\mathcal{A}$ is the collection of Hausdorff $\alpha$-measurable sets.

Now I have two questions:
1 Is there such a case that  $\delta_1 \l \delta_2$ then $\mathcal{H}_{\alpha,\delta_2}(E) \l \mathcal{H}_{\alpha,\delta_1}(E)$? I have the confusion because properties of Lebesgue measure imply that the covering sets in definition of Lebesgue measure can be modified to have the arbitrarily small diameter.

2 Is there some subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ that is not Hausdorff $\alpha$-measurable?

Comment: You have to enclose each bit of math stuff between two dollar signs. So, you write \$\beta \ne 2\$ to  get $\beta \ne 2$.

Comment: I fixed things until I ran out of enthusiasm.

Comment: I don't understand what *3 down vote favorite* is supposed to mean at the beginning of your post. More importantly, you should correct "$\delta_1 \l \delta_2$" and "$\mathcal{H}_{\alpha,\delta_2}(E) \l \mathcal{H}_{\alpha,\delta_1}(E)$". Did you want to write "$\delta_1 \le \delta_2$"?

Comment: I have no idea about meaning of Question 1, since earlier you are saying that ${\mathcal H}$ is monotonic with respect to $\delta$. For question 2, suppose that $\alpha=n$. Then, can't you use subsets which are not Legesgue-measurable? If not, Banach-Tarski paradoxical sets will surely do the job.